# Using foreach to subset based on level

Tags: r, ggplot2, foreach, subset

I'd like to save a series of graphs that look basically like this:

[image: plot]

which is generated by this code:

```
# orange is pre, red is intra, green is post
df$Month <- as.Date(df$activityDate)
ggplot(df, aes(x= Month, y= level)) + 
geom_jitter(colour= ifelse(df$phase == "post", 'springgreen4',
                        ifelse(df$phase == "pre", 'orange1', 'red3')),
                            size= 3, shape= 19, height=0.20, alpha = 0.6) +
theme_bw() +
    labs(title="EPA Levels Over Time", x= "Date", y= "EPA Level") +
    scale_x_date(labels= date_format("%m-%Y")) +
# main title
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face= 'bold', size=18)) +
# x axis title 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face= 'bold', size=14)) +
# y axis title
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face= 'bold', size=14)) +
# x axis tick mark labels
  theme(axis.text.x= element_text(hjust = 1, angle = 45, face= 'bold', size=10)) +
# y axis tick mark labels
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face= 'bold', size=12)) +
    facet_grid(~ epa) # show each epa
```

I want to use foreach() to loop over the levels in a column dfgraph$resident and save graphs that show only rows where i=dfgraph resident (see below):

```
foreach(i=levels(df$resident)) %do% {
  dfgraph <- df[df$resident==i,]
ggplot(dfgraph, aes(x= Month, y= level)) + 
geom_jitter(colour= ifelse(df$phase == "post", 'springgreen4',
                        ifelse(df$phase == "pre", 'orange1', 'red3')),
                            size= 3, shape= 19, height=0.20, alpha = 0.6) +
theme_bw() +
    labs(title="EPA Levels Over Time", x= "Date", y= "EPA Level") +
    scale_x_date(labels= date_format("%m-%Y")) +
# main title
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face= 'bold', size=18)) +
# x axis title 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face= 'bold', size=14)) +
# y axis title
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face= 'bold', size=14)) +
# x axis tick mark labels
  theme(axis.text.x= element_text(hjust = 1, angle = 45, face= 'bold', size=10)) +
# y axis tick mark labels
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face= 'bold', size=12)) +
    facet_grid(~ epa) # show each epa
  ggsave(filename = paste0(i, ".png"))
  }
```

But this yields me blank images. Any idea what's going wrong?

Also, I keep getting this error: "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): colour"

Comment: It's a bit difficult to judge without seeing the actual data. Can you remove the colouring from `geom_jitter`? I think it has to do with the coloring. I think you are setting to many colours. You maybe can try `geom_jitter(aes(color = phase))` and add `scale_colour_manual(values = c("pre" = "orange", "intra" = "red", "post" = "springgreen4"))`.

Comment: Yeah, removing the colour= from geom_jitter fixes the problem, but how else should I do my conditional point coloring?

Comment: you need to refer to `dfgraph` not `df` when setting the colour in your loop. a better approach would be to map colour as an aesthetic like @ricoderks suggests.